# Subquery in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, subquery

Let's put an easy example with two tables:

```
USERS (Id, Name, City)
PLAYERS (Id_Player, Number, Team)
```

And I have to do a query with a subselect in a loop, where the subselect is always the same, so I would like to divide it into two queries and put the subselect outside the loop.

I explain. **What works but it is not optimize:**

```
for($i=0;$i<something;$i++)
{
    $res2=mysql_query("SELECT Team from PLAYERS WHERE Number=$i 
        AND Id_Player IN (SELECT Id FROM USERS WHERE City='London')");
}
```

**What I would like to do but it doesn't work:**

```
$res1=mysql_query("SELECT Id from USERS where City='London'");
for($i=0;$i<something;$i++)
{
    $res2=mysql_query("SELECT Team from PLAYERS WHERE Number=$i 
        AND Id_Player IN **$res1**");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to make two queries instead of one? One query with a subselect would be faster then two standalone's. Also, can you tell uswhat error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT Team from PLAYERS 
    JOIN USERS on (Id_player=Id)
    WHERE Number BETWEEN $minID AND $maxID
    AND City='London'
    GROUP BY Team";

$results=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


// $results contain all the teams from London
// Use like normal..

echo "<ul>\n";

while($team = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    echo "\t<li>{$team['Team']}</li>\n";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT PLAYERS.*, USERS.City FROM PLAYERS, USERS WHERE USERS.City='London' AND PLAYERS.Number = $i`

Not the best way to do it; maybe a `LEFT JOIN`, but it should work. Might have the syntax wrong though.

James

**EDIT**

**WARNING: This is not the most ideal solution. Please give me a more specific query and I can sort out a `join` query for you.**

Taking your comment into account, let's take a look at another example. This will use PHP to make a list we can use with the MySQL `IN` keyword.

First, make your query:

`$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT Id from USERS where City='London'");`

Then, loop through your query and put each `Id` field one after another in a comma seperated list:

```
$player_ids = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
    $player_ids .= $row['Id'] . ",";
}

$player_ids = rtrim($player_ids, ",");
```

You should now have a list of IDs like this:

`12, 14, 6, 4, 3, 15, ...`

Now to put it into your second query:

```
for($i = 0; $i<something; $i++) 
{      
    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT Team from PLAYERS WHERE Number=$i          
    AND Id_Player IN $player_ids"); 
}
```

The example given here can be improved for it's specific purpose, however I'm trying to keep it as open as possible.

If you want to make a list of strings, not IDs or other numbers, modify the first `while` loop, replacing the line inside it with

`$player_ids .= "'" . $row['Id'] . "',";`

If you could give me your actual query you use, I can come up with something better; as I said above, this is a more generic way of doing things, not necessarily the best.

Comment: Thank you but let's imagine that $res1 was much more complicated, and without relation with the loop. Then it wouldn't be very optimized the way you say, right? Because it has to evaluate in each iteration the "USERS.City='London'". THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Placing SQL quires in loops can be very slow and take up a lot of resources, have a look at using JOIN in you SQL. It's not that difficult and once you've got the hang of it you can write some really fast powerful SQL.

Here is a good tutorial worth having a look at about the different types of JOINs:
http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php

Comment: A very good idea. My answer is more of an interim to getting the OP to use `JOIN`; looped queries can be horrible sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Running query in a loop is not a great idea. Much better would be to get whole table, and then iterate through table in loop.

So query would be something like that:

```
"SELECT Team from PLAYERS WHERE Number BETWEEN($id, $something) 
        AND Id_Player IN (SELECT Id FROM USERS WHERE City='London')"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$res1=mysql_query("SELECT Id from USERS where City='London'");
for($i=0;$i<something;$i++)
{
    $res2=mysql_query("SELECT Team from PLAYERS WHERE Number=$i 
        AND Id_Player IN **$res1**");
}
```

Would work, but `mysql_query()` returns a RESULT HANDLE. It does not return the `id` value. Any select query, no matter how many, or few, rows it returns, returns a result statement, not a value. You first have to fetch the row using one of the `mysql_fetch...()` calls, which returns that row, from which you can then extract the id value. so...

```
$stmt = mysql_query("select ID ...");
if ($stmt === FALSE) {
    die(msyql_error());
}
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $ids = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        $ids[] = $row['id']
    }
    $ids = implode(',', $ids)
    $stmt = mysql_query("select TEAM from ... where Id_player IN ($ids)");
    .... more fetching/processing here ...
}
```